# How to use the off-diagonal terms of the covariance matrix when calculating confidence intervals?

Tags: regression, matlab, nonlinear-regression, error

The nonlinear fitting routine I use is MATLAB's

```
fitnlm
```

and it gives the covariance matrix. How can I take into account the off-diagonal values of this matrix to obtain confidence intervals for each fitting parameter?

I have seen answers where only the the square root of the diagonal is taken. Assuming a normal distribution, these values are then multiplied to a t-distribution for a chosen probability. Is there an equivalent when there is correlation between parameters?

Comment: Do you want separate CIs for each parameter or do you want a *simultaneous confidence region* for them?